# Get email attachment and save into oracle table in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use google app script to retrieve email attachment,
below is my code to check if there any attachment in the email message

```
function testMail() {
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var mess=threads[i].getMessages()[0];
  if (mess.getAttachments().length>0)
  {
    //var filename=mess.getAttachments()[0].
    Logger.log(mess.getSubject());
    Logger.log(mess.getAttachments()[0].getName());
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx","xxxxxxx");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into blob_table (filnname,blob_field) values (?,?)");
    stmt.setString(1, mess.getAttachments()[0].getName());

    stmt.setBlob(2, mess.getAttachments()[0]);
    var res = stmt.execute();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();    

    break;
  }  
}
}
```

but the error "cannot find method setBlob prompt" when I run the script, I am able to save data to the table blob_table if I insert only the field filename, is there any special way to insert blob?

Thanks

Comment: hI, i found a way to insert the attachment to blob field

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the autocompletes or documentation you'll see that JDBC, unlike the rest of Apps Script, has its own notion of JdbcBlob which is not identical to Blob. (Every JdbcBlob is a Blob but not vice versa.) You can turn a regular Blob into a JDBC blob like this:

```
conn.createBlob().setBytes(0, myOriginalBlob)
```

where in this case `myOriginalBlob` is what you got from `mess.getAttachments()[0])`

Answer (score 0):

jdbcBlob and Blob are two different things.
In the line `stmt.setBlob(2, xxxx);`

xxxx is a jdbcBlob. If you have a Blob, you need to convert it into jdbcBlob before saving in DB.

```
var jdbcBlob = conn.createBlob();
jdbcBlob.setBytes(1, blob);
```

In your example, the correct approach would be

```
var jdbcBlob = conn.createBlob();
jdbcBlob.setBytes(1, mess.getAttachments()[0]);
stmt.setBlob(2, jdbcBlob);
```